# Adding custom column using 'activeadmin-axlsx' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, axlsx

I am using **activeadmin** gem in my application using Rails 4. I need excel download for which I am making use of **activeadmin-axlsx** gem.
I am able to get all the columns that exists in my database for the particular model in the excel sheet as its columns. However, what I want is, to add a column which does not exists in my database.

This is what I have tried until now

```
 column('start_date') do |date|
   date.start_date
 end
```

Here **start_date** is an attribute in my db and hence I get that column in the excel.

Now when I try to add another column End Date(which is not an attribute in the db), I get a blank column.

I have also tried the below snippet, referring to the [Github link for activeadmin-axlsx](https://github.com/randym/activeadmin-axlsx)

```
config.xlsx_builder.column('end_date') do |emp|
  emp.end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end
```

This gives a blank column in the excel

Can anybody help me achieve this?Or suggest any other gems that can be used with **activeadmin gem**?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add the attributes that do not exist in your database as an attribute accessor in your respective model.

For the above example,

end_date is not an attribute in the table, so in the model say Employee, add this

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_acessor :end_date

end
```

Here I am modifying end_time which is an attribute in database of type datetime to fetch only the date with the name of the column being **End Date**

In the app/admin/employee.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do 

  xlsx do 
    column('end_date') do |emp|
      emp.end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    end
  end
end
```

This would give you the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just define one like start_date. Did you try:

```
column(:end_date) do |resource|
  resource.end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end
```

Comment: Yes @baxang I did, since end_date is not an existing attribute in db it gives me a blank column.
So the way out is you define end_date as attribute_accessor in your model. This worked for me :)